# Is "over-dot balancing" (time derivative balancing) a "thing" in differential equations? Reference text?

Tags: symmetry, derivatives, calculus

This is a pattern I have noticed in some circumstances.  A homogeneous function (in the sense of [Euler's theorem](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Thermodynamics_and_Statistical_Mechanics/Book%3A_Heat_and_Thermodynamics_(Tatum)/02%3A_Partial_Derivatives/2.06%3A_Euler%27s_Theorem_for_Homogeneous_Functions)) which is a polynomial is one in which the argument appears in the same power in each term.  In my experience, multiple derivatives often follow the same pattern as binomial (or multinomial) expansion.

For example, consider the transformation to an inertial rectangular Cartesian coordinate system ($x^i$) from a rectangular Cartesian coordinate system ($x^\bar{i}$) which is rotating with angular velocity about a moving origin $\bar{\mathcal{O}}$.  Notice that each term on both sides of the equations has the same number of over-dots.  Notice also the similarity between the power (square) of a binomial and and the derivative of the centered part of the transformation formula for a moving point with coordinates $r^{\bar{i}}.$

$$\begin{aligned}
x^{i}=&x^{i}\left(x^{\bar{j}}\right)+x_{\bar{\mathcal{O}}}^{i}\\
e_{\bar{j}}^{i}=&\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial x^{\bar{j}}}\\
\delta_{ij}e_{\bar{i}}^{i}e_{\bar{j}}^{j}=&\delta_{\bar{i}\bar{j}}\\
r^{i}=&e_{\bar{j}}^{i}r^{\bar{j}}+x_{\bar{\mathcal{O}}}^{i}\\
\dot{r}^{i}=&\dot{e}_{\bar{j}}^{i}r^{\bar{j}}+e_{\bar{j}}^{i}\dot{r}^{\bar{j}}+\dot{x}_{\bar{\mathcal{O}}}^{i}\\
\ddot{r}^{i}=&\ddot{e}_{\bar{j}}^{i}r^{\bar{j}}+2\dot{e}_{\bar{j}}^{i}\dot{r}^{\bar{j}}+e_{\bar{j}}^{i}\ddot{r}^{\bar{j}}+\ddot{x}_{\bar{\mathcal{O}}}^{i}\\
\left(ta+tb\right)^{2}=&t^{2}a^{2}+2t^{2}ab+t^{2}b^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

The, admittedly limited, taxonomy I have for differential equations is as follows:

- **type:** ordinary or partial
- **order:** highest order derivative
- **degree:** highest power of the highest order derivative after the equation has been cleared of radicals and fractions in the dependent variable and its derivatives.

Notice that this does not address the number of times a lower order derivative appears.

To my mind, the facts that the number of over-dots (time derivatives) is the same in all terms, and the multinomial coefficients appear in the derivative of the centered part seem noteworthy.  This also seems related to homogeneous functions.

Is this a useful topic in the treatment of differential equations?

Comment: Are you talking about the Leibniz rule? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule. Note that time derivatives must also have the correct dimensions, i.e. differentiating with respect to t will add a dimension of time in the denominator.

Comment: That is clearly part of my question.  I will have to reflect on it to see if there is still a part remaining.  I am particularly interested in its usefulness in physics.  The only place where I have applied Euler's homogeneous function theorem is in the proof of the virial theorem.  https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath572/kmath572.htm